# Save Form with UserControl state with all the events

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form with variable number of UserControls. This UserControl allow adding/removing labels and has an event of changing the text of each label by additional small form. How to save the state of the Main Form with number of UserControls(with labels) from previous Form loading and editing and event of label name changing?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272470/save-properties-of-control-to-xml) how to save and load the properties to xml. As addition to save all the control you had on the form, loop through the controls and use a propertie in your settings class to save the control name. This can be used when you're instantiate / load the controls back up.